# Android menu crashs application

Tags: android

I have the following in my code and I want to switch to this new activity when I select it from the menu, but the app just keeps closing:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mi_baas:
                startActivity(new Intent("com.my.project.BAAS"));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    } 

}
```

Please help, 2 days so far.....

Comment: BAAS is an Activity..?

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this, assuming that by "just keeps closing", you mean that your app is crashing.

Comment: Yes BAAS is an activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `context` and `class` which is to be opened.

Your code should be like this.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mi_baas:
                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(),BAAS.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    } 

}
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: I'm getting the message 'Cannot resolve method getContect()'

Comment: You have to pass context there. if you are in fragment you have to call **getActivity()** or if you are in activity just pass **this**.